# Ошибка во время установки .msi

Tags: windows, msi

На 32 бит винде работала программа, перешёл на 64 бит винду, но уже не могу установить , ошибка

Error attempting to read from the source installation database: C:\WINDOWS\Installer(random code).msi

Comment: тут скорее всего дело не в разрядности винды, а в битом msi. MSI вытаскивали с другой машины?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov это просто архив скачан с гугла, странно то что на 64 бит 10 винде, все версии программы дают эту ошибку, когда стояла 32 бит проблем не было никаких, но странно у других людей ставится никто не жаловался на такую ошибку. Не хочется возвращаться на 32 бит винду на сегодня ((

Comment: Логи msiexec/кэша смотрели?

Comment: может поможет https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d